# Enum addition bitmask to a lookup value

Tags: sql, sql-server, enums, bitmask

I'm sure this question has been asked before, however if someone could steer me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it

We have an application that stores Ethnicity values in the database as integers.

```
0 - None
1 - IDoNotWishToFurnish
2 - HispanicOrLatino
4 - NotHispanicOrLatino
8 - Mexican
16 - PuertoRican
32 - Cuban
64 - OtherHispanicOrLatino
```

I want to be able convert all those summed integer values into their respected options

Results of the query would be something like this

```
   PersonID        Name     Ethnicity   Ethnicity_Name
    1           Joe Smith   26          HispanicOrLatino,Mexican,PuertoRican
```

If this isnt the right approach on querying this information please let me know what would be the best way.

I need to extract data so I can integrate into Salesforce

Comment: This is not at all clear to me what you are trying to do. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: tried to make it clearer hopefully this makes more sense

Comment: This is not a great way to deal with data. You really should normalize your data instead of bitmasking like this.And if you are going to bitmask you need to use 1,2,4,8. NOT 1,2,3. What happens in your current approach if you add a 4? You have no way of knowing if it is a 4 or both 1 and 3.

Comment: my attempt to give an example was way off. I've edited the question and included the right enum values 1,2,4,8,16 .. etc. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: This still isn't a great way to handle multiple selections. A properly normalized data structure is a lot easier to work with.

Comment: Did you see the answer from ColdSolstice? It is exactly what you have to do for this. And the comments about normalization are spot on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is the ability to use a bitwise flag. However your arithmetic won't work. Each EthnicityID would have to be a power of 2 (1,2,4,8...) for you to add all the numbers together into one number (not recommended from a DB performance standpoint).

```
CREATE TABLE Application (
   ApplicationID INT,
   EthnicityID INT,
   PRIMARY KEY (ApplicationID, EthnicityID)
);

CREATE TABLE Ethnicity (
   EthnicityID TINYINT,
   EthnicityName VARCHAR(128),
   PRIMARY KEY (EthnicityID)
);

INSERT INTO Ethnicity (EthnicityID, EthnicityName)
VALUES
   (1, 'Asian'),
   (2, 'Hispanic'),
   (4, 'Latino');
```

The EthnicityIDs have to all be a Power of 2 for this to work. If you use the [Flags] attribute in C# for your enum this will occur automatically.

If you wanted save someone who stated they were Asian & Latino (1+4=5), your query would look like this

```
DECLARE @InputApplicationID INT = 1;
DECLARE @InputEthnicityIDs INT = 5; --Asian | Latino

INSERT INTO ApplicationEthnicity (ApplicationID, EthnicityID)
SELECT @InputApplicationID,
    E.EthnicityID
FROM Ethnicity AS E
WHERE E.EthnicityID & @InputEthnicityIDs = E.EthnicityID; --bitwise AND operation


SELECT * 
FROM ApplicationEthnicity;
```

Again from a database performance perspective I'm not a fan of doing it this way. I don't imagine the Ethnicity table will be very large so it probably won't be a big deal, but you are not utilizing the index on EthnicityID doing it this way (and you are breaking 3NF).

To query Ethnicity query by application, you can run the following:

```
DECLARE @QueryApplicationID INT = 1;
SELECT STUFF(
    (Select ', ' + E.EthnicityName AS [text()]
     FROM dbo.ApplicationEthnicity AE
       INNER JOIN dbo.Ethnicity E
          ON AE.EthnicityID = E.EthnicityID
     WHERE AE.ApplicationID = @QueryApplicationID
      FOR XML PATH (''))
   ,1,1,'')
```

Comment: I've edited the question to represent the correct enum values.

Comment: This is the best way to deal with this type of denormalized data.